# HighchartsAdapter is no longer available, what is the new way to call adapterRun?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I had this original question [HighCharts: How to use reflow to allow auto-resize after changing size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754511/highcharts-how-to-use-reflow-to-allow-auto-resize-after-changing-size)

Where the answer I got was this block of code below:

```
if (!vs.chartObject.reflowNow) {
    vs.chartObject.reflowNow = vs.chartObject.reflowNow = function() {
        this.containerHeight = this.options.chart.height || window.window.HighchartsAdapter.adapterRun(this.renderTo, 'height');
        this.containerWidth  = this.options.chart.width  || window.window.HighchartsAdapter.adapterRun(this.renderTo, 'width');

        if (vs.expandedType === 'max') {
            this.setSize(this.containerWidth, (this.containerHeight-220), true);
        } else {
            this.setSize(this.containerWidth, this.containerHeight, true);
        }

        this.hasUserSize = null;
    }
 }

 vs.chartObject.reflowNow();
```

However now for some reason I'm getting `undefined` on this: `window.window.HighchartsAdapter`

Which breaks my chart expand code now.

When I console logged window.window and expanded it, I can see that there is no longer a `HighchartsAdapter`.

[image]

Do any of you HighChart developers know which method replaces `HighchartsAdapter` now?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 4.2.1 `HighchartsAdapter` is removed from the core. That means Highcharts lib doesn't depend on jQuery or any other library anymore.

In the source of old versions you can find that method:

```
adapterRun: function (elem, method) {
    return $(elem)[method]();
},
```

That means, if you are using jQuery, you can replace:

```
window.window.HighchartsAdapter.adapterRun(this.renderTo, 'height')
```

with:

```
$(this.renderTo).height();
```

And to be honest, you always could use that solution - it's more readable than using `adapterRun()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was so lost :) My chart is expanding again correctly, slight bug when resetting the size, but working on that next...

Comment: Would you mind posting the non-JQuery solution as well?

Comment: Something like `document.getElementById("container").offsetHeight` (or `clientHeight` if padding/border/scrollbar should not be included)?