# Highchart is not resizing dynamically when used as a angular directive

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I have written highcharts as angular directive as below :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("hc", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('options', function(newVal, oldVal){
                if (newVal) { Highcharts.chart(element[0],scope.options);}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But on resize of screen , highchart div is not resizing. It is always 600x400. How to dynamically resize the highchart chart?

This is how I use exactly angular directive  : https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gwukyjhj/
But reflow function of highcharts is not applying here.

Comment: Could you provide a working JSFiddle demo where this occurs?

Comment: I think this topic may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754511/highcharts-how-to-use-reflow-to-allow-auto-resize-after-changing-size.

Comment: Added example fiddle. That is how I use highcharts as angular directive. If you resize that fiddle window, you can see that highcharts reflow function is not applying. Width and height of charts are not changing.

Comment: Same problem. Highcharts directive has a bug, switching to the variable approach

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by converting angular element to class. Somehow if I am using directive as class instead of element high-chart re flow functionality works.

```
<div class="hc" id="container"></div>
```